# Flipcards ... broken on mobile

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have been working on some flipcards to put on a website (using bootstrap 4 and jQuery) and all appears fine on Desktop but when I test it on mobile things get strange, the back facing card disappers and the front facing card gets flipped.

I have been stating at the code for a while now, and trying to resolve the issue, with no luck, so I have put it into a codepen and decided to ask for some help.

I am guessing it is something obvious but the code is here https://codepen.io/magical1/pen/paaNmB.

I imagine the offending code is here

```
@media not all,
not all {
    .front,
    .back {}
    .back {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .front {
        z-index: 4;
    }
    .card-container:not(.manual-flip):hover .back,
    .card-container.manual-flip.hover .back {
        z-index: 5;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: `not all, not all` should be?

Comment: if i change it to `@media screen` or `@media screen,screen` I get the `.card` `.front` loading in reverse ... not sure how to get around this?

Comment: Okay so it turns out that setting it `all` Instead of `not all` and removing the extra `.hover` class that I had on the parent div resolved the issue, I hate when you are too close to something and no matter what you try you can’t see the bug ... thanks @RokoC.Buljan ... it was just the nudge i needed :)

Comment: Glad you made it! :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Turns out although it works in the codepen, it doesn’t work in the live site, now I am not getting the back side showing up, I can see it underneath the other layers , but cannot get it to show up

Comment: @MichaelBalloonatic: Just sending a reference to compare, I don't think you need the media tag https://codepen.io/IamManchanda/pen/zoaWdW

Comment: @Yasir thanks for the example, unfortunately that one just vanishes on mobile when you click on the div ... still trying to find a way to make it work on all devices

Comment: Hey, i've resolved your issue, please see solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be on the `transform-style` on apple devices.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/oEEZwJ

Update CSS as follows:

```
body {
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 239, 252);
}

.card-container {
    perspective: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card-container:not(.manual-flip):hover .card,
.card-container.hover.manual-flip .card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-container.static:hover .card,
.card-container.static.hover .card {
    transform: none;
}

.card {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    /*transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
    position: relative;
    border: none;
}

.front,
.back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    z-index: 3;
}

.btn-simple{
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

btn-simple i{
    font-size:13px;
}

.back .btn-simple {
    position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
    top: 4px;
  width 26px;
}

.card {
    border-top-left-radius: 24px;
    border-top-right-radius: 24px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 24px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 24px;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

.grad1 .front,
.grad1 .back {
    background-image: linear-gradient(141deg, rgb(114, 178, 204) 0%, rgb(106, 150, 196) 34%, rgb(88, 104, 189) 66%, rgb(88, 104, 219) 100%);
}

.grad2 .front,
.grad2 .back {
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(253, 139, 165) 0%, rgb(193, 71, 111) 100%);
}

.grad3 .front,
.grad3 .back {
    background-image: linear-gradient(141deg, rgb(228, 190, 143) 0%, rgb(228, 158, 158) 28%, rgb(209, 105, 164) 100%);
}

.card-container,
.front,
.back {
    width: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 24px;
    border-top-right-radius: 24px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 24px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 24px;
    min-height: 420px !important;
}

@media all, all {
    .front,
    .back {}
    .back {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .front {
        z-index: 4;
    }
    .card-container:not(.manual-flip):hover .back,
    .card-container.manual-flip.hover .back {
        z-index: 5;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million that fixes the problem, apologies for the delay in getting back to you about this!

This is the perfect solution :)